# Why can't change ttk.Entry background color?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Here is a code simple to illustrate my problem :

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
s = ttk.Style(root)
s.configure(
    'TEntry',
    background='blue',
    foreground='red'
)
s.map(
    'TEntry',
    foreground=[('focus', 'pink')],
    background=[('focus', 'green')]
)
Entry = ttk.Entry(root)
Entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

No matter what I do the Entry's background stays white. On the other hand, the foreground changes color well.
Any idea please ? I'm runing Python 3.11.1 under Windows 11.

Comment: Try using different themes via `s.theme_use()` because some styles may work in certain themes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

- Add `layout`.
- Add `StringVar()`
- Add `fieldbackground`

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
              
s = ttk.Style()
 
s.layout("EntryStyle.TEntry",
                   [('Entry.plain.field', {'children': [(
                       'Entry.background', {'children': [(
                           'Entry.padding', {'children': [(
                               'Entry.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                      'sticky': 'nswe'})], 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                      'border':'2', 'sticky': 'nswe'})])

s.configure("EntryStyle.TEntry",
                 background="blue", 
                 foreground="red",
                 fieldbackground="black")

var = StringVar()

e = ttk.Entry(root, style="EntryStyle.TEntry", textvariable=var, font='sans 15 bold')
e.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the `StringVar` when there is `<ttk.Entry>.get()`?

Comment: You can omitted if you wanted to do. It up to you. As for me I do workaround.

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading. Using `StringVar` isn't necessary to solve the problem of changing the background color, but this answer gives the impression that it is.