# Combining aspects of multiple themes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a tkinter GUI (which I've simplified for the purpose of this question), and in the code I wish to take on the 'vista' theme, however this theme does not allow me to configure the `fieldbackground` element of the ttk.Entry widget, but the 'clam' theme does. So what I want to ask is, is there is a comprehensive way to keep the 'vista' theme, and also configure this element?

In the code attached I have found a work around, where I declare the theme as 'clam', copy and reconfigure the style of it's native `TEntry` widget, then place my Entry widget as required with its style defined as my new DIY style, and then finally declare the theme as 'vista'. This way my Entry widget maintains the style allocated from Frankenstein 'clam' widget, and all other widgets fall in line with the theme defined by 'vista'.

I know it's not normal to mix themes, but there's a few things I would like to know:

- Is my workaround a viable solution, or might I run into trouble down the line?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?
- More general question, but is there no way to define certain elements in certain themes, e.g. `fieldbackground` in 'vista'.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class myGUI(tk.Tk):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True) #Find out what this is doing **
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 

        self.frames = {}  
    
        for F in [MainPage]:

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")

        self.show_page(MainPage) #First page to be shown

    def show_page(self, cont):  

        frame = self.frames[cont]  
        frame.tkraise()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        
        
        ###### Workaround:
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam') #Declare 'clam' theme
        
        # Copy layout of clam 'TEntry', and edit the copy as required
        style.layout("Custom.Entry", style.layout('TEntry'))
        style.configure("Custom.Entry", **style.configure('TEntry'))
        style.map("Custom.Entry", **style.map('TEntry'))
        style.configure('Custom.Entry', foreground='#ffffff', fieldbackground='#333333')
        ######

        self.frame_heading = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Frame Heading")
        self.frame_heading.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=7, padx=(20,20), sticky='nesw')

        button_a = ttk.Button(self.frame_heading, text="Button A", command='')
        button_a.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=(10,10), sticky='ew')

        # Apply copied theme to Entry widget, and then after change theme to vista
        entry_box = ttk.Entry(self.frame_heading, style='Custom.Entry')
        entry_box.insert(1, 'Test Entry Text')
        entry_box.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=(10,10), sticky='ew')

        self.frame_heading.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.frame_heading.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4), weight=1, uniform='a')
        
        #Revert back to vista theme
        style.theme_use('vista')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = myGUI()
    app.geometry('300x300+400+200')  
    app.mainloop()
```

Apologies if this question has been covered before, but I haven't been able to find anything thoroughly covering this online. Any questions just ask. Thanks!

Comment: This [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639955/8349697), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75109797/8349697) looks like what you want to do.

Comment: If possible, you can use external packages like [CustomTkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter).

Comment: @8349697 Perfect thanks! those examples should definitely help me out, I assume it will be a similar route to change the ttk.LabelFrame fieldbackground when in the vista theme.